# The name Resource does not exist in the current context

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I just created a sample application with a button in xamarin.Android after building I am getting the error resource does not exist in the current context.
I didn't change the namespace also.

MainActivity.cs code:

```
int count = 1;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        button.Click += Button_Click;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Button)sender).Text = string.Format("{0} Clicks!",count++);
    }
```

In google they said namespace change will give this error but I have same namespace in Resources.designer.cs.

How to handle this error?

I have tried just creating a new project and opened MainActivity.cs file without modifying anything still I am getting this error

Comment: Hi, delete the bin and obj folder, restart Visual Studio.

Comment: @Robbit I have the same problem here, I try this but does'nt work...

Comment: @LucasPrestes，hi, can you show your problem? What is your VS version?

Comment: I have the VS2015 I ask for an coworker and he say I need to have VS2017 to use xamarin without these type of problems...

Comment: Okay I am using VS2015